# Inverse linear transformation from $P_1(\Bbb R)→P_1(\Bbb R)$ question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Define $T:P_1(\Bbb R)→P_1(\Bbb R)$ by $T(ax+b)=(2b−a)x+(b+a)$. Show that T is both one-to-one and onto, and find $T^{-1}$.

I know how to check whether it is one-to-one and onto, but how do I find $T^{-1}(ax+b)$?

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:*** Write $T^{-1}(p)=cx+d$ for every $p\in P_1 (\Bbb{R})$ and try to calculate $T^{-1}\circ T$.